# Obtener la última posición GPS usando FusedLocationProviderApi Google Play Services en Android

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Intento crear un ejemplo simple, solo que obtenga una vez la posición GPS pero usando Google play Services, es decir haciendo uso de [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

                Log.d(TAG, "checkIfLocationEnabled: " + checkIfLocationEnabled(getBaseContext()));

            }
        });


        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            this.startActivity(myIntent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: " + connectionResult.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStart: ");
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop: ");
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
        super.onDestroy();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Todo lo que voy encontrado por la red, es usando `IntentService` a mi me interesa solo obtener una vez, no tener un servicio todo el rato obteniendo posiciones en background.

Es decir al pulsar el `fabButton` que se obtenga lat, lon, altitud, bearing, velocidad etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener la ubicación actual de fused provider hay que usar

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
```

Tén en cuenta que esto busca la ultima ubicacion reportada por ese provider, que **puede ser null** si ninguna app llamo a este provider recientemente.

Comment: En caso de recibir null, ¿como puedo forzar la obtención de la posición? solo me interesa leer una vez, es para una app estilo "find my car" para marcar el estacionamiento.

Comment: Hola amigo @Webserveis , forzosamente debe existir una "primera ocasión" para obtener la localización, esto para que getLastLocation() pueda retornar un valor diferente a null...

Comment: @Webseveis, si este provider resulta en null podrías crear un Location artificial como fallback para asegurar una buena experiencia de usuario algo como  `Location lastLocation = new Location("fake_default_provider");
        lastLocation.setLatitude(-34.603684);
        lastLocation.setLongitude(-58.381559);`

Answer (score 1):

Grácias a la respuesta de @jirngaray:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {

        Log.d(TAG, "getLastLocation: " + mLastLocation.toString());

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Ubicación no encontrada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```